# torrc on a Mac?

Tags: configuration, mac, vidalia

It isn't completely obvious where the `torrc` file needs to reside on a Mac (say, 10.6). In `Settings->Advanced`, it appears to be in `Applications/TorBrowser_en-US/Library/Vidalia/torrc`. But there is also a `USER/.tor` directory.

Also, FWIW, whenever I use the Tor configuration file editor to try to change that file (for example, adding an `ExitNodes` line), I get a

> Error at line 1:

error message. I seem to be unable to successfully edit that file.

I'm confused. On a Mac, if I want to add an `ExitNodes` line, where exactly does it go and how do I get it there?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6147) in some versions of Vidalia which has been floating around for a while.

Try removing any commented lines from the `torrc` file before saving. Supposedly you only need to remove the initial two lines but removing the rest might be best.

Comment: Aargh. I removed the initial two lines, and then was able to add an ExitNodes line. Hooray. But then I wanted to try it with that line removed, so I tried to edit it out. It absolutely would not save edited out. So I did a fresh reload of the Browser BUndle and tried it again. But, but, now the torrc is different. It has just ONE comment line at the top. I remove that, and I can't save. I remove all the comment lines, and I gat a bizzare error --

Comment: Try again ... I removed the initial two lines in the torrc, and then, as advised, was able to add an ExitNodes line. Hooray! But then I wanted to try it with that line removed, so I tried to edit it back out. It absolutely would not save the edited out version. I was stuck with that ExitNodes line. So I did a reload of the Browser Bundle to try it again. But now the torrc is different! It has just ONE comment line at the top. I remove that line, and get the same error. I remove all the lines, and now get a weird "Transition not allowed: While Tor is running, changing Data Directory ..." error.

Comment: Maybe stop Tor before editing? But in Linux, that's not necessary. Restart required to implement changes.

Answer (score 0):

I [asked](https://mastodon.social/@qbi/106399695665876101) for a solution and got multiple answers. Recent macOS systems save their `torrc` inside the directory `~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/`. Important: Between `Application` and `Support` is a space.

So the whole path is

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc
```